# reactivecocoa5.0 need convert to swift 3.0 and there are lots of error after that

Tags: swift3, reactive-cocoa-5

reactivecocoa 5.0 has supported swift 3.0, but after importing reactivecocoa 5.0 from cocoapods and opening my project, xcode show me that I need convert swift 2.3 to 3.0, and after that, there are lots of errors, why? reactivecocoa is not support swift 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Always Embed Swift Standart Libraries" set to YES for all needed targets